# I can swear i once did " new Literal("<b>hello there</b>");

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0

I could have sworn i have done this somewhere - im using 2.0 right now - was this something i found in a later version?  IE: pass the content of a Literal in the constructor

I remember myself saying 'huh, and all this time i created a new instance and then set the text property' - or did I go to sleep drunk that night?  And if not, WHY NOT!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe [LiteralControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol.aspx)?

```
this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<b>hello there</b>"));
```

Note it doesn't maintain ViewState so it must be added on each request.